# Does UJT work as amplifier?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, analog, bjt, oscillator

I had got a question in job interview " **Draw a circuit of common emitter amplifier using Non Bipolar Transistor.**"

As the question said Non Bipolar, so I assumed that it might be related to UJT. But I haven't found any common emitter amplifier related to UJT. It would be helpful if anyone could provide me the answer.

Comment: They're probably thinking about FETs

Comment: @peufeu You're probably right.but FETs don't have emitters, so the question is kind of flawed in that case.

Comment: Yup.  UJT's got a lot of interest 50 years ago when they came out, because they were weird.   But I doubt there are any new designs that use them, and they're inherently snap-action so wouldn't be a first choice for a linear amplifier.

Comment: @peufeu FET has source, not emitter.

Comment: @TimWescott can you give a circuit diagram ? Just a basic diagram. No details.

Comment: Not really -- UJT's were before my time, and I'm not exactly young.  I don't think I've ever seen an attempt to make a linear amplifier from a UJT because *they inherently don't work that way*.

Comment: COULD be a typo in "NPN bipolar transistor". Might not be, though.

Comment: I'm with Brian on this one - O and P are right next to each other and it's very likely that a 'helpful' spell-checker would have 'corrected' NPN to Non.

Comment: @BrianDrummond is correct. This is done by auto Autocorrect.

Comment: Yah .. it should be a typing mistake caused by autocorrect.

Comment: That would be really weird- input on one base and output on the other base? It might be possible, and would certainly be a curiosity. True UJTs (eg. 2N2646) are obsolete, even when I was getting started so many  years ago we used PUTs, which are a thyristor structure, rather than UJTs for timing instruments. (*UJTs have two bases and one emitter).

Comment: The only thing I know with emitters are BJT, UJT, and IGBT. This might be useless, but I think it is possible to build and amplifier using IGBT.